# PHP - Getting numbers when reading korean characters

Tags: php, laravel, utf-8, laravel-5.1

I have following url with some Korean characters at end of the url:

```
http://localhost/example/popular-tags/고양이
```

Now I am reading `고양이` from url like this which is used in Laravel5 for read data from url string:

```
$TagName = str_slug(Request::segment(2), "-");
```

but getting number `eab3a0ec9691ec9db4` not `고양이` characters.

Any idea how to get Korean characters.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://www.stillat.com/blog/2015/01/16/laravel-helper-functions-strslug/), `str_slug` translates to ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Laravel's helpers to work with UTF-8 slugs. I've tried it and it has really big problems (in routes, helpers etc). I even wrote [my own package](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-russian-slugs) to work with UTF-8. You can try it, cause if you want to get URLs like `http://localhost/example/popular-tags/고양이` and you don't use `!#$@` and similar characters in URL, it will work for you. Or you can copy some [slug creation code](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-russian-slugs/blob/master/src/Slugs.php) from it and use it inside you own project.

Also, you can simplify things and just use:

```
Route('example/popular-tags/{slug}' ...`
```

And in controller:

```
public function index($slug)
{
    $data = Model::where('slug', $slug)->get();
```